# How to setup a ASP template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have a website which is created using HTML/CSS/JQuery/JavaScript. I want to convert it to an ASP.net website. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

From my homepage I would like to keep three DIV visible at all times. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

My Solution Explorer looks like this:

[image]

When I create a new website template in VS, I have the following `MasterPage.master` page:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my question is what does the the above page should store?
Let's say I want to create another page, "page2.aspx" which will have different contents beside the three things in the screenshot, which will appear always, how do I do that?

From browsing, it looks like I can also add a Web Form which gives the page a "Default" name.

I am just confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can add as many `ContentPlaceHolder` than you want in your page. In your case, you probably need one for each `div`s that ar always in your page.

Comment: Where do I put those ContentPlaceHolder? Like in a page on its own? I can see I can call by the ID of the CPH.

Comment: You really want to use webforms, ew ;) asp.net mvc a lot better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think learning a little bit more about how master pages work would probably serve you well. This is a tutorial from the ASP.NET site and looks like it should get you to the point of reusing the layout like you're asking: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/creating-a-site-wide-layout-using-master-pages-cs

Comment: Really great tutorial! Thanks.